# C++ lambda function - how to return closest vector element compared to target

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, comparator

I have a already-sorted vector called vec, and a target variable. The goal is to return the closest-to-target vector element.

I tried to use C++11 lambda function with [=] to capture outside variable

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5};
    double target = 3.14159;

    int res = min(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [=](int v1, int v2) -> bool {
            return abs(v1-target) < abs(v2-target);
        });

    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get res=3, but it returns an error:

```
error: cannot convert 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >' to 'int' in initialization
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong algorithm. `std::min` operates on two specific object passed as is, or on a `std::initializer_list`. For containers, use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) instead. It returns an iterator, which needs to be dereferenced.

```
auto res = std::min_element(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [=](int v1, int v2) -> bool {
        return abs(v1-target) < abs(v2-target);
    });

// Make sure that the range wasn't empty, i.e. res != vec.cend()...

const int min = *res;
```

Note that you might want to consider narrowing down the scope of your lambda closure by explicitly capturing the object that you need (in your case only one after all). And also consider passing `.cbegin()` and `.cend()` when you don't modify the container in question.

Comment: Yes! Once again, it would have been nice if begin/end returned const_iterators and you could get normal iterators with mbegin/mend...

Comment: Also note that this does not use the sortedness of the range (i.e., this solution is `O(n)` instead of `O(log(n))`). Not that I would expect the performance difference to matter, but I find it worth noting.

Answer (score 4):

A solution that might potentially be more efficient and readable could use `lower_bound` to find the greater of two elements that could potentially be returned.

```
int custom_bound(std::vector<int> const& vec, double target) {
    if (vec.empty()) {
        // throw or make the function return `optional`, choose to taste
    }

    auto lb = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target);

    if (lb == vec.end()) {
        return *(lb - 1);
    } else if (lb == vec.begin()) {
        return *lb;
    } else {
        const int up = *lb;
        const int down = *(lb - 1);
        return std::abs(up-target) < std::abs(down-target) ? up : down;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this can't be easily done as a one-liner. It doesn't require any custom functors, though; it merely exploits the fact that the number must lie in between (inclusive) `lower_bound` and the iterator one before the LB.

We can make another observation that `up` will be equal or greater to `target`, while `down` can only be smaller. Hence the condition could be replaced with

```
up-target < target-down
```

which removes the need for `std::abs`.

Comment: You have UB if `target` is greater than the last element of `vec`. You would have to check against `vec.end()` first (and return `*(lb-1)` in that case).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Good point. The more I edit this, the more I dislike this solution, but I think I'll leave it here simply as an alternative implementation.

Comment: May I suggest an [iterator returning function](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G5p0nYc0pXWf54rI)? Note that the OP tagged the question as C++11, so the return type can't be a `std::optional`.